# Profile Page cannot updating

Tags: django

I have a simple profile page and the information filled here comes in the form. The problem is that if I change a value it redirects to pages. I don't get an error but that update is not written to the database

views.py

```
def update_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile_data = form.cleaned_data
            profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=request.user)           
            profile.first_name = profile_data['first_name']
            profile.last_name = profile_data['last_name']
            profile.save()
            messages.success(request, "Update is successful")
        return redirect('/pages/')
    else:
        form = ProfileUpdateForm()
        return render(request, 'profile.html', {'form': form})
```

template.html

```
<form class="form" method="POST" action='{% url "update" %}'>
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                          <label>First Name</label>
                          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="{{ user.first_name }}"" value="{{ user.first_name }}">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                      
      
                            <div class="col">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Last Name</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="{{ user.last_name }}"" value="{{ user.last_name }}">
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col d-flex justify-content-end">
                          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="profile">Save Changes</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
```

forms.py

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):   
    
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'plz', 'street', 'street_no', 'city']
        widgets = {                           
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),                                
        }
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

any help?

Answer (score 1):

The (very) likely reason is because you only show `first_name` and `last_name` as HTML fields, but your `ProfileUpdateForm` has `plz`, `street`, etc. which are all required fields, so it errors on that.

You should exclude the fields you don't use, like:

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']
        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

It is likely also better to just let the `ProfileUpdateForm` do the work:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@login_required
def update_user(request):
    profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Update is successful')
            return redirect('/pages/')
    else:
        form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=profile)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'form': form})
```

and normally one only redirects in case the form *is* valid, in case it is not, the page is normally rerendered with the form.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

---

> **Note**: While most forms do not process media files, it is probably better to pass [**`request.FILES`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) to the form anyway, such that if you later add an extra media field, all views that use the form will indeed handle the files properly.

Comment: I simplified the template page, other fields are available in the form. In the code you sent, @login_required gives an error. (Argument of type "(request: Unknown) -> (HttpResponseRedirect | HttpResponsePermanentRedirect | HttpResponse | None)" cannot be assigned to parameter "function" of type "_VIEW@login_required" in function "login_required") I made the necessary imports. As it is, the values are not updated and it redirects to pages

Comment: @gegentierversuche: that's not an error of Python, that is a type checker, and apparently a schizophrenic one :) Most typecheckers fail to grasp the metaprogramming that Django does :).

Comment: @gegentierversuche: just print `form.errors` *before* it enters the `return render...` clause.

Comment: print(form.errors) does not give any message. Only redirects to page

Comment: @gegentierversuche: you should only redirect in the `if form.is_valid()` clause, not as in the question where you even redirect if the form is not valid.

Comment: i put form.error message both of the clause form.is.valid or else but still I cannot see any feedback

Comment: @gegentierversuche: it is not the print that should change, you should simply only redirect in case the form *is* valid, otherwise it violates the HTTP specs regarding status errors.

Comment: ok the case is a bit more complicated. I have got user auth_user table with first_name and last_name and I have separate userprofiles table with same fields. I think the values comes from auth but db writing to userprofile.

Comment: @gegentierversuche: well that makes not much sense either. The fields should *not* be duplicated. You can simply retrieve these from `profile.user.first_name` when needed, otherwise you introduce a *data duplication* pattern, which is a (severe) antipattern: keeping fields in sync turns out to be a hard problem, even on the same database. Normally you should store the data one, and only one time.

Comment: @gegentierversuche: you can make properties to "shortcut" the `.user` access, but duplicating database fields only introduces more trouble, since all signals, etc. will need to be modified accordingly, and introduces all sorts of non-atomic behavior. I would suggest to make two Django forms: one to alter the user, one for the profile, and each with distinct fields.